# Letsencrypt certificate not working in CentOS 6.8 32 bit version

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, centos6, lets-encrypt, lets-encrypt-webapp-renewer

I am trying to install Letsencrypt certificate in CentOS 6.8 32 bit for Apache.  It used to work earlier, but now it is giving the following error:

```
Skipping bootstrap because certbot-auto is deprecated on this system.
Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore.
Certbot cannot be installed.
Please visit https://certbot.eff.org/ to check for other alternatives.
```

I have been checking the site:

> https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centos6-apache

and I see that 64 bit CentOS 6 is only supported.  The message shown on the site is:

```
Supported architectures: Certbot only supports CentOS/RHEL 6 systems running on the x86_64 architecture. To use Certbot on another architecture, you will need to upgrade your OS.
```

Does it mean that CentOS 6 32 bit version is no longer supported?  What will happen when the installed certificates on CentOS 32 bit have to be renewed?

And if CentOS 32 bit is no longer supported, what is the date from which this support is revoked?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Can you please share the possible solutions ?

Comment: got similar for 6.10

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using an older version of Certbot 0.35.0 and using the following command to renew the certificate:

```
/usr/local/bin/certbot-auto --no-self-upgrade --no-bootstrap renew
```

It has worked on CentOS 6.8 successfully.

Comment: it does not worked for me,  CentOS 6.10